# Backup and restore a SQL Server database through java

Tags: java, sql-server

In my Java project, I wish to allow users to backup and restore the project SQL Server database.

Here is what I'm trying to do using JDBC, without success:

```
Statement callback = con.createStatement();

String dbackup = "BACKUP DATABASE databaseName TO DISK = 'Path for the backup file";

if(callBackupDbase != null) {
  callBackupDbase.execute(dbackup);
}
```

How can I backup and restore the SQL Server database from Java?

Comment: Please define exactly what "without success" means here (eg was there an error, nothing happened, it hangs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio create Schedule task

You can do it  Management/Maintenance Plan
or You Create from SQL Server agent / Job
3-5 clicks
You can do PowerShell as well

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JDBC, you could use the following code. Modify it according to your need.

```
public String dumpDB(DataSource dataSource) {

        Connection dbConn = null;
        DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = null;
        String columnNameQuote = "\"";
        try {
            dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();
            dbMetaData = dbConn.getMetaData();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to database: "+e);
            return null;
        }

        try {
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String catalog = "*";//props.getProperty("catalog");
            String schema = "*";//props.getProperty("schemaPattern");
            String tables = "*";//props.getProperty("tableName");
//            ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getTables(catalog, schema, tables, null);
//  To get all table and schema, we can use null
            ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getTables(null, null, null, null);

            if (! rs.next()) {
                System.err.println("Unable to find any tables matching: catalog="+catalog+" schema="+schema+" tables="+tables);
                rs.close();
            } else {
                // Right, we have some tables, so we can go to work.
                // the details we have are
                // TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
                // TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
                // TABLE_NAME String => table name
                // TABLE_TYPE String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
                // REMARKS String => explanatory comment on the table
                // TYPE_CAT String => the types catalog (may be null)
                // TYPE_SCHEM String => the types schema (may be null)
                // TYPE_NAME String => type name (may be null)
                // SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME String => name of the designated "identifier" column of a typed table (may be null)
                // REF_GENERATION String => specifies how values in SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME are created. Values are "SYSTEM", "USER", "DERIVED". (may be null)
                // We will ignore the schema and stuff, because people might want to import it somewhere else
                // We will also ignore any tables that aren't of type TABLE for now.
                // We use a do-while because we've already caled rs.next to see if there are any rows
                do {
                    String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                    String tableType = rs.getString("TABLE_TYPE");
                    if ("TABLE".equalsIgnoreCase(tableType)) {
                        result.append("\n\n-- "+tableName);
                        result.append("\nCREATE TABLE "+tableName+" (\n");
                        ResultSet tableMetaData = dbMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, "%");
                        boolean firstLine = true;
                        while (tableMetaData.next()) {
                            if (firstLine) {
                                firstLine = false;
                            } else {
                                // If we're not the first line, then finish the previous line with a comma
                                result.append(",\n");
                            }
                            String columnName = tableMetaData.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                            String columnType = tableMetaData.getString("TYPE_NAME");
                            // WARNING: this may give daft answers for some types on some databases (eg JDBC-ODBC link)
                            int columnSize = tableMetaData.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
                            String nullable = tableMetaData.getString("IS_NULLABLE");
                            String nullString = "NULL";
                            if ("NO".equalsIgnoreCase(nullable)) {
                                nullString = "NOT NULL";
                            }
                            result.append("    "+columnNameQuote+columnName+columnNameQuote+" "+columnType+" ("+columnSize+")"+" "+nullString);
                        }
                        tableMetaData.close();

                        // Now we need to put the primary key constraint
                        try {
                            ResultSet primaryKeys = dbMetaData.getPrimaryKeys(catalog, schema, tableName);
                            // What we might get:
                            // TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
                            // TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
                            // TABLE_NAME String => table name
                            // COLUMN_NAME String => column name
                            // KEY_SEQ short => sequence number within primary key
                            // PK_NAME String => primary key name (may be null)
                            String primaryKeyName = null;
                            StringBuffer primaryKeyColumns = new StringBuffer();
                            while (primaryKeys.next()) {
                                String thisKeyName = primaryKeys.getString("PK_NAME");
                                if ((thisKeyName != null && primaryKeyName == null)
                                        || (thisKeyName == null && primaryKeyName != null)
                                        || (thisKeyName != null && ! thisKeyName.equals(primaryKeyName))
                                        || (primaryKeyName != null && ! primaryKeyName.equals(thisKeyName))) {
                                    // the keynames aren't the same, so output all that we have so far (if anything)
                                    // and start a new primary key entry
                                    if (primaryKeyColumns.length() > 0) {
                                        // There's something to output
                                        result.append(",\n    PRIMARY KEY ");
                                        if (primaryKeyName != null) { result.append(primaryKeyName); }
                                        result.append("("+primaryKeyColumns.toString()+")");
                                    }
                                    // Start again with the new name
                                    primaryKeyColumns = new StringBuffer();
                                    primaryKeyName = thisKeyName;
                                }
                                // Now append the column
                                if (primaryKeyColumns.length() > 0) {
                                    primaryKeyColumns.append(", ");
                                }
                                primaryKeyColumns.append(primaryKeys.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
                            }
                            if (primaryKeyColumns.length() > 0) {
                                // There's something to output
                                result.append(",\n    PRIMARY KEY ");
                                if (primaryKeyName != null) { result.append(primaryKeyName); }
                                result.append(" ("+primaryKeyColumns.toString()+")");
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // NB you will get this exception with the JDBC-ODBC link because it says
                            // [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function
                            System.err.println("Unable to get primary keys for table "+tableName+" because "+e);
                        }

                        result.append("\n);\n");

                        // Right, we have a table, so we can go and dump it
                        dumpTable(dbConn, result, tableName);
                    }
                } while (rs.next());
                rs.close();
            }
            dbConn.close();
            return result.toString();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use Options | File Templates.
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** dump this particular table to the string buffer */
    private static void dumpTable(Connection dbConn, StringBuffer result, String tableName) {
        try {
            // First we output the create table stuff
            PreparedStatement stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+tableName);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

            // Now we can output the actual data
            result.append("\n\n-- Data for "+tableName+"\n");
            while (rs.next()) {
                result.append("INSERT INTO "+tableName+" VALUES (");
                for (int i=0; i<columnCount; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        result.append(", ");
                    }
                    Object value = rs.getObject(i+1);
                    if (value == null) {
                        result.append("NULL");
                    } else {
                        String outputValue = value.toString();
                        outputValue = outputValue.replaceAll("'","\\'");
                        result.append("'"+outputValue+"'");
                    }
                }
                result.append(");\n");
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to dump table "+tableName+" because: "+e);
        }
    }
```

Note: you have to create DataSource yourself. Look at the following usage sample.

```
System.out.print(dumpDb(yourDataSource));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create something similar to backup and restore specific tables in a live database?